# Loading items dynamically in jcarousel

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I am using JCarousel to display pictures from the DB into  JCarousel.

I am retrieving 500 pictures from the DB (for example) but i want to display only 50 pictures in jcarousel.

**This is my Code to populate the JCarousel**

```
  if ($("input[id$='hid_RowCount']").val() == 1) {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({ scroll: 7
    })


    function JCarouselJquery(jsonData){
        jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        itemLoadCallback: {onBeforeAnimation: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback}
    });
```

}

```
    function mycarousel_itemLoadCallback(carousel, state)
    {
       for (var i = carousel.first; i <= carousel.last; i++) {
       if (carousel.has(i)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (i > jsonData._items.length) {
                break;
            }

            carousel.add(i, jsonData._items.length[i-1]);

            }
        };
```

I am breaking my head to complete this task.

It will be of great help if some one provide some ideas or sample code.

Comment: It will be of great help if you provide the code you have now.

Comment: @user3 , we implemented carausal at www.allposters.com and it loads only 4 images first , when you click next it loads next 4 images, let me know if you need this kind of solution , i will explain you in detail

Comment: I have added more details as u have asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@user ,

You shouldn't load 500 picuters from the database.

You should have some id in the database or path, The images should come from some image server.So it will be fast.

Write an API which gets you a maximum of 50 images per page.

In the caraousal , whenever you click next , swap the ids and src of the images from the next 4 images

We have implemented the same here http://www.allposters.com

Comment: I Saw the website which you mentioned...Its really nice idea.Can u give me more details of how u implemented it????

Comment: Can u pls tell how you displayed the images in JCarousel dynamically on Next button click.I tried a lot but it did not work out for me...can you pls provide ideas or sample code how you did it????